# Entering values into an array, from a loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I'm retreiving score & course_code from my table, so that all the courses that have a score less than 40 should be copied into an array $carry_over.

```
var_dump($carry_over) only gives "Array" when i run the script.
```

Please how can i put/get the course_code of those courses that have a score of <40?
  Thanks for the help. I most appreciate it.

```
    $carry_over = array(); 
          while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc      ($query8)) {
 if ($row8['score'] < 40) {
$carry_over = array( 'm.course_code' =>      $row8['m.course_code']) ;
} 
}
var_dump($carry_over);
```

**Query8**

```
        $query8 = mysql_query("SELECT  m.          score , m.course_code
    FROM    maintable AS m  
 INNER JOIN students AS s ON
 m.matric_no = s.matric_no
 INNER JOIN courses AS c ON
 m.course_code = c.course_code
 WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'
 AND m.level = '".$level."'")
 or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: How about print_r()? Also why not change query to only have where score < 40? Also, your array may only have one value with how you are making $carry_over = to a new array each time it loops through from what I see. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Please expanciate on what you mean  here ....."Also, your array may only have one value with how you are making $carry_over = ...."

when i do print_r($carry_over) i still got "Array".
Thanks i appreciate it.

Comment: Well let's keep things simple, replace your current $carr_over = array('m.course_code' => etc... line with the following: array_push($carry_over, $row8['m.course_code']); and then instead of var_dump use print_r($carry_over); Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the help. When i update with your code. I only got "Array()" from the print_r($carry_over).

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that $carry_over is being assigned anything? Can you echo something inside that if() statement to confirm it is working? I am now assuming that the $carr_over array is never being assigned anything new.

Comment: I did 
    $numbers = mysql_num_rows($query8) and it retured 2...and that is correct. 

Then i'm sure i have 
    $carry_over = array(); at the beginning of the script.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below :

```
   $carry_over = array(); 
    while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query8)) 
    {
      if ($row8['score'] < 40)
      {
        $carry_over[$row8['score']] = $row8['m.course_code']) ;
      } 
    }
    var_dump($carry_over);
```

Comment: When i did your query i got nothing. The when i tried print_r($carry_over) i got "Array()"

Comment: Then I think it's not comming in condition if ($row8['score'] < 40)

Comment: Thanks for the help. What can i do to make it enter the if statement. Thanks

Comment: I think we should discuss over chat now.

Comment: I wish i could but i'm on mobile. Will it be okay there.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "What can i do to make it enter the if statement",I dont' know  what do u want to say? If all data is not in condition your array will be surely empty

Comment: I did $numbers = mysql_num_rows($query8)
and it retured 2...and that is correct

Comment: check value of score for both records.should be < 40

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8985/discussion-between-dotman14-and-teez)

Answer (score 0):

Try using print_r for dumping arrays and use this:

```
$carry_over[] = array(...
```

to add an element to an array,

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried both. I still get same result. print_r($carry_over) gives "Array"

Comment: @dotman14 Maybe you have an empty array. Check it with `count()` function. You could also improve your query by adding `AND score<40` and removing the if sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the help... The count() returned nothing. Does that mean it's empty? What can i do next?

Comment: @dotman14 It probably means it's empty. Try `mysql_num_rows($query8)`. If it returns 0 (or nothing) then your query condition must be wrong somehow.BTW in PHP you can do this: "SELECT * FROM $var" and $var gets replaced with itss value.

Comment: I did $numbers = mysql_num_rows($query8) and it retured 2...and that is correct.

Comment: Well, my last idea is `print_r($row8)` and look what it returns.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8986/discussion-between-dotman14-and-phpxp)